# How do I send JSON to Asp.NET Webservice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I have a javascript object that I am serializing using JSON2 library. I am then trying to pass this JSON string to a ASP.net webservice. I have changed the webmethod to try several different parameter configurations but they all result in a '500 - Internal Server Error'

Can someone give me a clue?

```
 function postDataToService(data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:2686/DataCollectionService.asmx/StoreDataOut",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: data,
        success: showSuccessNotice,
        error: showFailureNotice,
        dataType: "json"
    });

} //postdatatoservice

function convertDataToJSON(jsObj) {

    return JSON.stringify({ list: jsObj });

} //converdatatojson
```

Web Service:

```
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class DataCollectionService : WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string StoreDataOut(List<string> list)
    {
        return "Complete";
        //model functionality
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check the Event Log to get the details of the exception? Or use Fiddler or Firebug to check for further details in the 500 response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it..

**Step 1** : I wrapped the JS object in another object that contains a property that matches the parameter name at the web method. Notive the quotes around the

```
return JSON.stringify({'json':jsObj});
```

**Step 2** I then serialized this new 'wrapper' object with JSON.stringify().

**Step 3** Parameter name at web method matched posted json property name. Type is 'object'

```
 public string StoreDataOut(object json)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the code you provided and was able to post to the webservice without issues.

Some questions:

1. What does data look like?
2. What is the 500 server error?  Can you browse the webservice directly without errors? http://localhost:2686/DataCollectionService.asmx/StoreDataOut
3. I noticed in your data to send you never call `convertDataToJSON()` was this a typo?  If not perform the ajax post like the following:

```
   $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:2686/DataCollectionService.asmx/StoreDataOut",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: convertDataToJSON(data),
            success: showSuccessNotice,
            error: showFailureNotice,
            dataType: "json"
    });
```